# Pick sets of numbers {1,2,3} from a set of sets { {..}, {..}, {..} } such that all elements are unique

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm interested in a efficient algorithm to do the following job:

- I've a set of sets that are comprised of three numbers each.
- Within such a subset, the number are unique.
- But they can occure several times in other subsets.
- The target is to pick e.g. 3 subsets, such that the elements are only
  occure once.

For example: { {1,2,3} , {3,4,5} , {6,7,8} , {5,7,9} }

- the 2nd subset has 3 in common with the 1st subset.
- the 4th subset has an element in common with the 2nd and 3rd subset.
- When now a number of subsets is picked, that can not be. each element
  can only occure once.

I implemented a something that does the job, but I guess that can be done more efficient. How? might there even be a constant-time algorithm with `map`s or so?

- I used a `list` for implementing the set because I remove picked or
  excluded subsets (fast remove).
- Subsets are implemented using `vector`s.
- To keep track of already picked numbers, I use a `set`.

[Watch it here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37a8aad6ed2f8ce8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

random_device rd;
mt19937 rng(rd());

// pickes a random entry from a vector and returns an iterator to that element.
list<vector<int>>::iterator randomEntry(list< vector<int> >& v)
{
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, v.size()-1); // guaranteed unbiased
  auto it{ begin(v) };
  advance(it, dis(rng));
  return it;
}

int main()
{
  // a collection of possible sets
  list< vector<int> > collection;
  collection.emplace_back( vector<int>{51,9,22} );
  collection.emplace_back( vector<int>{11,5,74} );
  collection.emplace_back( vector<int>{61,9,35} ); // 2nd element in common with 1st entry
  collection.emplace_back( vector<int>{19,54,66} );
  collection.emplace_back( vector<int>{53,86,35} ); // 3rd element in common with 3rd entry
  collection.emplace_back( vector<int>{11,3,55} ); // 1st element in common with 2nd entry

  // pick three -independent- sets form the collection
  vector< vector<int> > picked;
  set<int> elements;

  while(picked.size()<3)
  {
    auto entry{ randomEntry(collection) }; // iterator to a randomly choosen entry

    bool unused{ true };
    for(const auto i : *entry)
    {
      if( elements.find(i) != cend(elements)) // if it already exists in elements, its already used.
        unused= false;
    }
    if(unused)
      picked.emplace_back( *entry );
    collection.erase(entry); // in any chase, remove == don't pick it again.
  }

  // all the elements printed should only appear once.
  for(const auto& i : collection)
  {
    for(const auto j : i)
      cout<<j<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your code is working and you are only looking for improvements, you should post ist on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

> I've a set of sets that are comprised of three numbers each.
>
> ... The target is to pick e.g. 3 subsets, such that the elements are only occure once.
>
> ... but I guess that can be done more efficient. How?

Since your goal is to pick an arbitrary number *p* of disjoint subsets (with 3 as an example), then this is exactly the [Set Packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), which is one of [Karp's 21 NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).

In the question, you mention that each set has 3 elements (this time, not as an example). Unfortunately, this version is still NPC. Fortunately, though, this means that [there is an approximation algorithm with with a factor of ~50%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing#Complexity).

It is therefore extremely unlikely that you will find a polynomial-time algorithm solving this for a general *p*. Looking at your code, I am doubtful it is correct. It is a (random) greedy algorithm, and it seems possible to construct scenarios (inputs + random choices) where it will pessimistically claim there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map (hash in c++)

Iterate over the sets.

For Each set check if one of it's numbers is in the map.
 if not add the numbers to the map and add this set to the unique sets
if its in the map, continue to the next set.